# Undo & Redo function not working as expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create an undo/redo function for `jQueryUI .draggable` at the moment I have a function but doesn't work as expect, here is my funcion:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editable').draggable({
    stop: stopHandlerDrag,
    start: startHandlerDrag

  });
  
});

var historyApp = {
  stackStyle: [],
  stackId: [],
  counter: -1,
  add: function(style, id) {

    ++this.counter;
    this.stackStyle[this.counter] = style;
    this.stackId[this.counter] = id;
    this.doSomethingWith(style, id);

    // delete anything forward of the counter
    this.stackStyle.splice(this.counter + 1);
  },
  undo: function() {
    --this.counter;
    this.doSomethingWith(this.stackStyle[this.counter], this.stackId[this.counter]);
  },
  redo: function() {
    ++this.counter;
    this.doSomethingWith(this.stackStyle[this.counter], this.stackId[this.counter]);

  },
  doSomethingWith: function(style, id) {

    //Check if make buttons undo/redo disabled or enabled
    if (this.counter <= -1) {
      $('#undo').addClass('disabled');
      $('#redo').removeClass('disabled');
      return;
    } else {
      $('#undo').removeClass('disabled');
    }

    if (this.counter == this.stackStyle.length) {
      $('#redo').addClass('disabled');
      $('#undo').removeClass('disabled');
      return;
    } else {
      $('#redo').removeClass('disabled');
    }

    console.log(style + ' - ' + id);
    //Apply history style
    $('#' + id).attr('style', style);

    console.log(this.counter + ' - ' + this.stackStyle.length);
  }
};

//Stop Handler Drag
function stopHandlerDrag(event, ui) {
  console.log('stop drag');
  var style = $(ui.helper).attr('style');
  var id = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
  historyApp.add(style, id);

}

//Star Handler Drag
function startHandlerDrag(event, ui) {
  console.log('start drag');
  var style = $(ui.helper).attr('style');
  var id = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
  historyApp.add(style, id);

  //Dettach all events
  $('#' + id).draggable("option", "revert", false);
  //reassign stop events
  $('#' + id).draggable({
    stop: stopHandlerDrag,
    start: ''
  });

}

//Click Events For Redo and Undo
$(document).on('click', '#redo', function() {
  historyApp.redo();
});

$(document).on('click', '#undo', function() {
  historyApp.undo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<span id="undo" class="btn btn-sm btn-success disable">Undo</span>
<span id="redo" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger disable ">Redo</span>                                

<p id="P1" class="editable" style="left: auto; top:auto;">Drag #1</<p>
<p id="P2" class="editable" style="left: auto; top:auto;">Drag #2</<p>
<p id="P3" class="editable" style="left: auto; top:auto;">Drag #3</<p>
```

And here is a [Working code demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXzZKq)

Now, the problem is that for example if you run my code and drag the elements in the following order (Drag #1, Drag #2, Drag #3), and then you click on `undo` sometimes you will have to click twice, and then if you drag in that order and the click on `undo` to restore all the elements as at te beginning and then `drag elements #1 and #2 and then click on undo` you will notice that only the #1 element is going to comeback to his possition, so my question is what I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this? I think that maybe my counter is wrong or something is wrong with my var `historyApp`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to append a logic to check if the style to `undo` or `redo` differs from the prev/next state:

```
        add: function (style, id) {
            var preIndex = this.counter;
            if (this.counter == this.stackStyle.length - 1)
            {
                ++this.counter;
            }
            else
            {
                this.counter = this.stackStyle.length;
            }
            this.stackStyle[this.counter] = style;
            this.stackId[this.counter] = id;
            this.doSomethingWith(style, id);
        },
        undo: function () {
            --this.counter;
            while ($('#' + this.stackId[this.counter]).attr('style') == this.stackStyle[this.counter])
            {
                --this.counter;
            }
            this.doSomethingWith(this.stackStyle[this.counter], this.stackId[this.counter]);
        },
        redo: function () {
            ++this.counter;
            while ($('#' + this.stackId[this.counter]).attr('style') == this.stackStyle[this.counter]) {
                ++this.counter;
            }
            this.doSomethingWith(this.stackStyle[this.counter], this.stackId[this.counter]);

        },
```

Comment: With this I only have to click one time tu execute my undo function, but the other problem is there, drag the elements in this order: #1, #2, #3, click undo button to put the elements at his beginning place, then drag elements #1 and #2 and then click undo button, you will se that only element #1 is moved to his place

Comment: @MiguelFlores, I've edited the functions `add`, `undo` and `redo` for a better handling on `counter` in state arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your logic. Here's a `StateMaker` I made myself. Don't copy it letter for letter, but it shows you the logic.

```
function StateMaker(initialState){
  var o = initialState;
  if(o){
    this.initialState = o; this.states = [o];
  }
  else{
    this.states = [];
  }
  this.savedStates = []; this.canUndo = this.canRedo = false; this.undoneStates = [];
  this.addState = function(state){
    this.states.push(state); this.undoneStates = []; this.canUndo = true; this.canRedo = false;
    return this;
  }
  this.undo = function(){
    var sl = this.states.length;
    if(this.initialState){
      if(sl > 1){
        this.undoneStates.push(this.states.pop()); this.canRedo = true;
        if(this.states.length < 2){
          this.canUndo = false;
        }
      }
      else{
        this.canUndo = false;
      }
    }
    else if(sl > 0){
      this.undoneStates.push(this.states.pop()); this.canRedo = true;
    }
    else{
      this.canUndo = false;
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.redo = function(){
    if(this.undoneStates.length > 0){
      this.states.push(this.undoneStates.pop()); this.canUndo = true;
      if(this.undoneStates.length < 1){
        this.canRedo = false;
      }
    }
    else{
      this.canRedo = false;
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.save = function(){
    this.savedStates = this.states.slice();
    return this;
  }
  this.isSavedState = function(){
    var st = this.states, l = st.length; sv = this.savedStates;
    if(l !== sv.length){
      return false;
    }
    function rec(o, c){
      var x, z;
      if(typeof o !== typeof c){
        return false;
      }
      else if(o instanceof Array){
        for(var n=0,q=o.length; n<q; n++){
          x = o[n]; z = c[n];
          if(x && typeof x === 'object'){
            return rec(x, z);
          }
          else if(o !== c){
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      else if(o && typeof o === 'object'){
        for(var n in o){
          x = o[n]; z = c[n];
          if(x && typeof x === 'object'){
            return rec(x, z);
          }
          else if(o !== c){
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      else if(o !== c){
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
      if(!rec(st[i], sv[i])){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Implementation with jQuery UI would look something like:

```
var dragging;
function DragMaster(yourDraggable){
  var d = yourDraggable, p = d.offset(), sm = new StateMaker({left:p.left, top:p.top})), states = sm.states, t = this;
  function ls(){
    if(states.length){
      return states.slice(-1)[0];
    }
    return false;
  }
  this.update = function(){
    var cp = d.offset();
    sm.addState({left:cp.left, top:cp.top});
    return this;
  }
  this.undo = function(){
    sm.undo(); d.offset(ls());
    return this;
  }
  this.redo = function(){
    sm.redo(); d.offset(ls());
    return this;
  }
  this.save = function(){
    sm.save();
    return this;
  }
  this.getStates = function(){
    return states;
  }
  this.getSavedStates = function(){
    return sm.savedStates;
  }
  this.init = function(){
    return {
      start: function(){
        dragging = d;
      },
      stop: function(){
        t.update();
      }
    }
  }
}
var yd = $('#yourDraggable'), dm = new DragMaster(yd);
yd.draggable(dm.init());
$('#undo').click(function(){
  if(dragging === yd)dm.undo();
});
$('#redo').click(function(){
  if(dragging === yd)dm.redo();
});
```

Now you can create `new DragMaster()`s and send `.init()` into draggable.

Note:

If you want to see if the current state is the saved state to change the color of your save button then `StateMakerInstance.isSavedState()` is what you can use.